# Sequelize Tables (Beginner Question) Node.js

Tags: node.js

Ok so I just started looking into databases yesterday

index.js: https://hatebin.com/pvqnubsrrs

database.js: https://hatebin.com/csgvmvolfz

I just want it to insert into the DB,
**how would I accomplish that?**
Someone told me it's creating a new DB, but when I run the command it says the table doesn't exist

The error says:

```
Error: SequelizeDatabaseError: SQLITE_ERROR: no such table: PointsSystems
```

However, I cannot find a spot in the code where I use PointsSystems, I only use PointsSystem, without the `s`

Edit: Thank you SigFried for making this more readable.

Comment: [Sequelize docs](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-instances.html)

Comment: No problem, however, your question is simple enough, that's why I'm referencing the `Sequelize` documentation in my comment above. Cheers.

Comment: @sigfried I've looked at the docs several times, I still have been able to resolve the no such table error,

Answer (score 0):

The error says `PointSystems` because, by default, `Sequelize` will pluralize the name you gave to the table. Your code looks O.K, the only missing part and the solution to your problem is the `await sequelize.sync({ force: true })}`. I made a [little example](https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-mendeleev-dyh6f) to show you how it's done in a very basic way.

You should be able to find out why the `sequelize.sync()` methods is needed if you read [this](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-instances.html).